# Android Internal jpg nullpointerexception

Tags: android, bitmap, internal, fileinputstream

Hello folks really stuck on this, im a newbie to Android. I'm trying to display internal (dat/data/)jpg images (not on sdCard) in a list view using img.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(file.toString()));

I know my code is a bit messy and i will refactor later but i just want to get this piece working so I can move forward. Many thanks.

I keep getting

```
07-31 11:27:08.905: D/AndroidRuntime(17470): Shutting down VM
07-31 11:27:08.905: W/dalvikvm(17470): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at com.walkingroutes.beta01.RouteList$1.setViewValue(RouteList.java:142)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.bindView(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:131)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:256)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2271)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1156)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4816)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1850)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1102)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1275)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-31 11:27:08.965: E/AndroidRuntime(17470):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-31 11:27:09.005: D/dalvikvm(17470): GC_CONCURRENT freed 259K, 3% free 10981K/11271K, paused 21ms+6ms, total 88ms
07-31 11:27:09.005: D/dalvikvm(17470): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 40ms
```

The Code:

```
public class RouteList extends BaseActivity {
    Cursor c;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    MainActivity mainAct;
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);
    ArrayList<String> l;
    ArrayList<String> l2;
    ArrayList<String> row_details;
    Cursor cursor;
    ListView myList;


    public JSONArray getArray() throws JSONException {
        db.open();
        JSONArray j = new JSONArray(db.readJSONFeed("http://www.example.com/api/all"));
        return j;
    }

    public void onClick2(View v){

    }
    public Long getCount(){
        db.open();
        return db.countRoutes();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.route_list);
        Log.d("RouteList","getAllRoutes");
        myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.route_list);
        RouteList.this.setupList();

    }//end of onCreate
    @Override
      protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }
    @Override
      protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        // UNregister the receiver
        //unregisterReceiver(receiver); 
      }


    private void setupList(){
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.list_title);
        Long count = getCount();
        text.setText(" " +count + " trails");
        db.open();
        db.createImagesDB();
        db.open();
        cursor = db.getAllRoutes(); 
        startManagingCursor(cursor);


        String[] fromFieldNames = new String[]{
            DBAdapter.KEY_NAME,DBAdapter.C_DISTANCE,DBAdapter.C_COUNTY,"cache"
        };
        int[] toViewIDs = new int[]{
                R.id.route_list_title,R.id.route_list_detail,R.id.route_list_county,R.id.icon
        };     
        //Create an adapter to mount columns with the UI.
        SimpleCursorAdapter routeListAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                RouteList.this,
                R.layout.route_list_row,
                cursor,
                fromFieldNames,
                toViewIDs
        ); 



        //AMEND THE LIST DATA

        routeListAdapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {
            @Override
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int column) {
                if( column == 4 ){ // let's suppose that the column 0 is the date

                    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);
                    String fn = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("cache"));
                    if(fn != null){
                        Log.d("routeListAdapter","File name is: "+fn);
                        String filePath = getApplication().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+ File.separator + fn;
                        File f = new File(filePath);
                        if (f.exists()) {
                            Log.d("routeListAdapter","File does exist!");

                            Bitmap bitmap = null;
                            FileInputStream fin = null;
                            String string = "hello";
                            try {
                                fin = openFileInput(fn);
                                Log.d("routeListAdapter","Got fin");
                                File file = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath(fn);
                                Log.d("routeListAdapter","file://"+file.toString());
                                img.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(file.toString()));
                            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            try {
                                fin.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }//if f exists
                    }else{
                        Log.e("routeListAdapter","File name not found!");
                    }
                    return true;
                }  
                if( column == 3 ){ 
                    TextView v = (TextView) view;
                    String distance = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("distance"));
                    distance += " km";  
                    v.setText(distance); 
                    return true;
                }  
                if( column == 2 ){ 
                    TextView v = (TextView) view;
                    String county = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("county"));
                   // county = "County: "+county;
                    String countyString = (String) county;
                    countyString = DBAdapter.getCounty(countyString);
                    v.setText(countyString);  
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        myList.setAdapter(routeListAdapter);

        // CLICK LISTENER
        myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,View arg1, int arg2, long id) {
                Log.d("onItemClick", String.valueOf(id));
                Intent i = new Intent(RouteList.this,DetailActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("_id", String.valueOf(id));
                startActivity(i);
                Log.d("onlistItemClick","activity started");
            } 
        }); 
        if(count <=  0){
            if(isNetworkAvailable()){
                startService(new Intent(RouteList.this,UpdaterService.class));
                routeListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {//else of if NetworkAvailible
                Toast.makeText(RouteList.this, "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("onCreate"," setupList start");

            }//end of if NetworkAvailible

         }

        //dialog.dismiss();
        //if(dialog.isShowing()){
        //   dialog.dismiss();
        // }
    }//end of setupList



    private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = null;
        int response = -1;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

        if(!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection)) throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");
        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
            httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConn.connect();
            response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
            if(response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                in = httpConn.getInputStream();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            Log.d("Networking",ex.getLocalizedMessage());
            throw new IOException("Error connection");
        }
        return in;
    }
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/android-detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available
    private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
      ConnectivityManager connectivityManager  = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
      NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
      return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }//END OF isNetworkAvailable

}//end of
```

Comment: The actual stack trace that tells you the line number? That's the line that's exactly where you're using something that is `null`

Answer (score 0):

I agree... must be the cursor returning a null value which binds to the  view